# row wise sorting in pandas dataframe and aggregation

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas

I have a table in pandas dataframe df

```
col1    col2     count
12       15        3
13       17        5
1        36        4
15       12        7
36       1         4
```

and so on....
what i want is to consider calues like '12 and 15' and '15 and 12' to be same, and also sum their count
and create a new dataframe df2
which has no repeated entries and their count to be added.
for eg.

```
col1    col2     count
12       15        10     #3+7
13       17        5
1        36        8       #4+4
```

and so on.
which method i should use to get that?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort your rows, then group and sum:

```
df[['a', 'b']] = df[['a', 'b']].apply(sorted, axis=1)
df.groupby(['a', 'b'], as_index=False)['c'].sum()
```

Comment: even if i am changing the axis to 1  am not getting right results

Comment: Yes, I posted a little prematurely. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: [see the snapshot of my current result](http://pasteboard.co/sCUP0VX44.png)